# Cluttered plot when plot area is called, need partitioning of plot area

Tags: python, plot

I'm putting my data together to plot the prices of homes in a fixed range, but have not had any luck doing this.

```
num_bins = 5
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data_process['HousingCost'], num_bins, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.title("Average Housing Sales Prices in Range",fontsize= 16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.xlabel('Average Housing Prices (median)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Counts', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

I would like this to plot in intervals of $50k (1st bar shows homes in the 0-50k range, next shows 50k - 100k range, etc), but have not had any luck.

How could I do this for this plot?

Any direction would be much appreciated!

[Housing prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwcAq.jpg)

Comment: Does `num_bins = 5` correspond to $50k wide bins?

Comment: That's what I thought I was, but it looks like I was incorrect in that. Increasing the number of bins does not help either.

Comment: So what intervals do you get for `num_bins = 5`? You may want to check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).